# "Mitochondria IS the powerhouse of the cell" - is this grammatically correct?

Tags: verbs, grammatical-number

In science as well as pop-culture, I've seen "Mitochondria is the powerhouse of the cell" in the singular.

However, "mitochondria" is the plural form of "mitochondrion", which leads me to think that the popular phrase is a grammatically incorrect one since it uses "is", whereas it should be using "are": Mitochondria are the powerhouse of the cell.

Am I missing something here? Is there a different aspect in the context of how these words are used generally in the scientific terminology, or the popular use of this phrase is just grammatically incorrect?

Comment: Don't worry about it happens all the time.  If I got upset every time I heard or read "... it depends what your criteria is.'  Now I endure my twinge in silence and move on.  The language itself is moving on too.

Comment: You're speaking English, not Greek. Think of it as a feminine in the singular and a neuter in the plural, if that will help. That would be _-a_ either way.

Comment: Nowadays, people say "data is".

Comment: @GEdgar "data is" is certainly he more common, but I'm actually hearing people say "data are" much more frequently these days than I did in the 00s or 90s. "Data science" is all the rage.

Comment: People talk about mitochondria in pop culture? Jailhouse rock or what?

Answer (score 3):

*Mitochondria* is a plural noun in standard usage, so the correct phrasing would be instead “mitochondria are the powerhouse of the cell”, “mitochondria are the powerhouses of the cell”, or “the mitochondrion is the powerhouse of the cell.”

The specific phrase "**mitochondria is** the powerhouse of the cell" or “**the mitochondria is** the powerhouse of the cell" appears to be a meme. Memes can proliferate even when they aren’t grammatical or well worded; it’s not exactly the same thing as “popular usage” of an ordinary, non-meme phrase or saying. What I mean is that the particular wording that you're asking about might be seen so often on the Internet only because of a choice made by a single author of some popular, highly reproduced online post.

My current suspicion is that this particular usage is actually not as common among scientists, and particularly not in edited documents such as textbooks, as the usage where *mitochondria* is plural and *mitochondrion* is singular. Singular *mitochondria* does occur occasionally in scientific texts, but I think it's more common for people to misremember it as occurring when in fact, a slightly different wording was used in the original text that the scientist wrote.

A search of Google Books turns up a number of texts that use the "powerhouse of the cell" wording without using the "mitochondria is" part; e.g.

- > the mitochondrion well deserves its popular nickname 'the powerhouse of the cell'

  (*A Guidebook to Biochemistry,* 4th edition, by Michael Yudkin and Robin Offord, 1980, [page 219](https://books.google.com/books?id=QcA5kBKwxVAC&pg=PA219&dq=powerhouse+of+the+cell&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjUn9m-3J_5AhWvIDQIHUeLBX8Q6AF6BAgCEAI#v=onepage&q=powerhouse%20of%20the%20cell&f=false))

Some textbooks also seem to use an appositive structure "mitochondria, the powerhouse of the cell", which also does not require "mitochondria" to be a gramatically singular noun.

However, I did find the following example of a published scientific book that uses "mitochondria is", so it isn't nonexistent in that context:

- > CONCEPT: The mitochondria is the energy modulator, the powerhouse of the cell.

  (page 7)

  > The mitochondria is reported to contain small amounts of nucleic acid.

  (page 8)

  (*[Cell Machinery](https://books.google.com/books?id=0DiPGPfZpC0C&pg=PT7),* Robert Leftwich, 1970)

Comment: As for a specific phrase from a scientific source, I think I don't have it on my hand, but your point about it being a meme is correct, however, I believe the meme itself originated from the same phrase found in our high-school text I believe.

Answer (score 2):

You're right to think it's incorrect. It is incorrect. Verb form should agree with the subject, so if using "mitochondria" (plural) for the subject, the verb should use the plural form "are".

However, this usage is ironic in that the phrase is perpetuated by its absurdity. It lives on despite no apparent source in part because the American education system has perpetuated it and in part because students of the English language and students of organic chemistry live to bond over mocking it for its failings. That is, the expression is flawed both in it's grammaticality and in it's capacity to convey useful information about cells.

Answer (score -4):

It would be, The mitochondria is the power house of the cell. In your example you had used a singular noun. When using a singular objective noun, ore often than not you will add the. One other tip is to check for the type of noun and how it is being used (objective, preperative, general, subjcet, etc.).

Comment: Verb should agree with subject, not object. "Many people people make a team," not, "Many people makes a team."